# Pending draw animation issue on Smart Eye Glass (AR Mode)

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Hi Sony SmartEyeglass team,

Currently, I'm using SmartEyeglass Developer Edition SED-E1. I'm developing a application that streaming video from Glass's Camera. For each camera frame, we detect faces and mark detected face on Glass by using SmartEyeglassControlUtils.sendARAnimationObject. The app works OK if the WLAN network between Glass & Phone is stable but when this connection is not stable, the drawing detected face on Glass is delayed a lot. It seems that the data of "SmartEyeglassControlUtils.sendARAnimationObject" is pending somewhere on SmartEyeGlass.apk app because they can be sent to Glass to displayed.
Therefore, could you guide me how to detect the WLAN network status (bandwidth or something like this) between Glass & Phone (Any API to detect this) so that we can stop calling SmartEyeglassControlUtils.sendARAnimationObject in case WLAN network is slow to prevent this issue?

Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no API to check WLAN network status of the connection.